# Change font size of sifr text

Tags: sifr

Is there any way to alter the font size of [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/) text after it has been rendered? I am creating a virtual poster mock-up, and I want to be able to have the user alter the size of the text on the fly (and without a refresh).

I've tried altering the font-size of the base text and changeCSS of the .sifr-root and .sifr-active, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no way to change the font size, other than removing the replacement and replacing the text again with a different size.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Styling) documenting sIFR v3 talks about text scaling, with some dire warnings ... But perhaps it works for your use case, and is worth testing?

Comment: Gave this a try, but redraw() was just giving me the same result each time